# Select Link after fetching label in frony of it

Tags: selenium, getelementbyid

i am writing a  selenium java code and at a particular webpage i want to select a link from a
group of links where each link has an emebeded text within a table. How can i select particular
link at this situtation. for eg.

```
run title--text 1
run title--text 2
run title--text 3
```

how can select specific run link for a specific title text? the text is not a label rather it is
 just simple text on the webpage.

i am using the following code:

```
verify.text("text 1");
```

it will only verify the presence of text ut it wont go towarads the link as linkof every execution is named RUN. so it will identify the corresponding run link?
The HTML code for the above is:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>TEST</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div align="center"><table class="module" width="630">

<tr>
<th class="banner" width="70">ACTION</th>
<th class="banner" width="560">REPORT TEMPLATE</th>
</tr>





 <tr>

 <td class="modulenav" width="70">
 <table class="innermodule" width="100%">



    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.abc.com/">Run</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.zxc.com">UnShare</a></td></tr>

    </table>
    </td>

    <td>
    <table class="innerModule" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td class="label" width="70">Title</td>
         <td width="490"><span class="listingHead">Incident Performance by Priority</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Description</td>
      <td class="listing"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Owner</td>
      <td class="listing"> Software Engineer&nbsp; Tel: </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Shared With</td>
      <td class="listing">

      Software Engineer &nbsp;Tel: <br>


      </td>
      </tr>


       <tr>
      <td class="label">Report Type</td>
         <td class="listing">Performance by Priority</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
     </td>
     </tr>
    <tr><td class="tableRuleNavy" colspan="2"></td></tr>

    <tr>

   <td class="modulenav" width="70">
  <table class="innermodule" width="100%">



    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.abc.com">Run</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.cxd.com">UnShare</a></td></tr>

  </table>
 </td>



 <td>
  <table class="innerModule" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td class="label" width="70">Title</td>
         <td width="490"><span class="listingHead">Incident Trend Analysis Report</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Description</td>
      <td class="listing"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Owner</td>
      <td class="listing">Software Engineer&nbsp; Tel: </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Shared With</td>
      <td class="listing">




       Software Engineer &nbsp;Tel: <br>


      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td class="label">Report Type</td>
         <td class="listing">Trend Analysis</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
<tr><td class="tableRuleNavy" colspan="2"></td></tr>

<tr>

<td class="modulenav" width="70">
  <table class="innermodule" width="100%">



    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.sdfds.com">Run</a></td></tr>



    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.asdg.com">UnShare</a></td></tr>


  </table>
</DIV>
</td>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Post the HTML content of it.

Comment: Actually the scenerio is there is a tempelate table which is different for every user. The title text can be in different order for different user so cannot use Xpath to click on the RUn link.  In the table there are two columns and multiple rows as per the requirement of the user. i want the user to enter the text and the corresponding run link should be clicked.

Comment: Thanks I got the scenario, but in order to post the code or give you an approach, we need at least the HTML part of the table, this would be give us an picture of how to retrieve the elements from the table.

Comment: yeah the HTML code for the above is: